# Advanced Indexing: I need to munge time series data to backfill all missing values for a specific timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, missing-data

Input 2D Data:

```
ticker, date, time, price
AAPL, 12-04-2021, 9:45:00, 10000
AAPL, 12-04-2021, 9:51:00, 10005
AMZN, 12-04-2021, 9:46:00, 10007
AMZN, 12-04-2021, 9:52:00, 10010
```

Desired output :

A backfilled hierarchical dataframe that can be indexed via Date, Timestamp and Instrument, but which has entries for all missing timestamps for every observed ticker and timestamp. The dummy data here is to show that there are 2 observed prices for AAPL at 9:45 A.M and 9:51 that don't intersect with the other two timestamp prices for AMZN. What I would like to do is have one time stamp entry for each observed index, and then use the next available time observation to fill this. So in essence I would like

`df["12-04-2021", "9:46:00", "AAPL"]` to return 10005, the observation at 9:51

`df["12-04-2021", "9:45:00", "AMZN"]` to return 10007, the observation at 9:46

Or in general the data needs to be recomposed to

```
ticker, date, time, price
AAPL, 12-04-2021, 9:45:00, 10000
AAPL, 12-04-2021, 9:46:00, 10005
AAPL, 12-04-2021, 9:51:00, 10005
AAPL, 12-04-2021, 9:52:00, 10005 [Should be the next available value in time possible]
AMZN, 12-04-2021, 9:45:00, 10007
AMZN, 12-04-2021, 9:46:00, 10007
AMZN, 12-04-2021, 9:51:00, 10010
AMZN, 12-04-2021, 9:52:00, 10010
```

This is sample dummy data but typically there would be many more date and tickers for a timestamp range of within market hours, I have thought about whether I should perform the backfill first or index the dataframe and then backfill it. I think I need to fundamentally understand how to set the dataframe such that the missing timestamps are assigned NA values, because whatever I try right now gives me a KeyError and not an NA Value.

I have tried

```
df = pd.read_csv(`DATA`, index_col=['date', 'time', 'ticker'])
df = df.stack(dropna=False)
df.update(df.groupby(['date', 'time', 'ticker']).bfill())
```

But I think I'm not fundamentally understanding how to assign the [date,time] columns as a universal field that must have either an observed value or NA to begin backfilling it. I get a key error for most combinations that I've tried.

Any ideas on how to understand this would be appreciated, thanks if you made it all the way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest convert `date` with `time`s to datetimes, then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with backfilling and forward filling missing values and then reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('date') + ' ' + df.pop('time'))

df = (df.set_index(['ticker','datetimes'])['price']
        .unstack()
        .bfill(axis=1)
        .ffill(axis=1)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='col2'))

print (df)
  ticker           datetimes     col2
0   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:45:00  10000.0
1   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:46:00  10005.0
2   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:51:00  10005.0
3   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:52:00  10005.0
4   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:45:00  10007.0
5   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:46:00  10007.0
6   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:51:00  10010.0
7   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:52:00  10010.0
```

---

```
df['date'] = df['datetimes'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetimes'].dt.time
print (df)
  ticker           datetimes     col2        date      time
0   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:45:00  10000.0  2021-12-04  09:45:00
1   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:46:00  10005.0  2021-12-04  09:46:00
2   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:51:00  10005.0  2021-12-04  09:51:00
3   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:52:00  10005.0  2021-12-04  09:52:00
4   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:45:00  10007.0  2021-12-04  09:45:00
5   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:46:00  10007.0  2021-12-04  09:46:00
6   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:51:00  10010.0  2021-12-04  09:51:00
7   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:52:00  10010.0  2021-12-04  09:52:00
```

Solution with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('date') + ' ' + df.pop('time'))

dates = df['datetimes'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()

f = lambda x: x.reindex(dates, method='bfill').ffill()
df = (df.set_index('datetimes').groupby(['ticker'])['price'].apply(f)
        .reset_index(name='col2')
        )
    
print (df)
  ticker           datetimes     col2
0   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:45:00  10000.0
1   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:46:00  10005.0
2   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:51:00  10005.0
3   AAPL 2021-12-04 09:52:00  10005.0
4   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:45:00  10007.0
5   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:46:00  10007.0
6   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:51:00  10010.0
7   AMZN 2021-12-04 09:52:00  10010.0
```

Comment: Thanks this does what I need exactly! as a follow-up question on efficiency, would you suggest using datetime.time(hour,min,second) to index `df['time'] = df['datetimes'].dt.time` or would you use the composite index of datetime + timedelta and create the lookup value on the fly as you iterate over dates and timestamps?

Comment: @fibonachoceres - For performance is better use timedeltas, in my opinion.

Comment: Wondering if there is an efficient way to perform this for  multiple columns, for example if instead of price we had Open High Low and Close and had to perform the same operations on all of them, the unstack here would treat the columns as a linear list of values while bfilling/ffilling

Comment: Passing list of columns for the groupby solution did it, thanks!